# CSS3 Transition: animating between 2 different gradients. incl jsfiddle

Tags: animation, css, css-transitions

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/PXdXr/1/

I would like to animate between 2 different gradients, have one fade in on hover.
My example shows what should happen, but it happens instantly, i want it to fade between them.

Just for reference here on SO(this is all in the jsfiddle):

```
.outerBorder {
    display:inline-block;
    /*border: 3px solid #4d4d4d;*/

   background: #4d4d4d; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4d4d4d), color-stop(100%,#0e0e0e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* IE10+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4d4d4d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
background: linear-gradient(top, #4d4d4d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* W3C */



-webkit-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;

}

.outerBorder:hover {
    display:inline-block;
    /*border: 3px solid #4d4d4d;*/

background: #d6f9ff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d6f9ff 0%, #9ee8fa 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d6f9ff), color-stop(100%,#9ee8fa)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d6f9ff 0%,#9ee8fa 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d6f9ff 0%,#9ee8fa 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d6f9ff 0%,#9ee8fa 100%); /* IE10+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d6f9ff', endColorstr='#9ee8fa',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
background: linear-gradient(top, #d6f9ff 0%,#9ee8fa 100%); /* W3C */

}

.innerBox {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    margin:5px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: I doubt there is support for gradient color animation yet..

Comment: A year and a half later, IE10 is the first browser to support gradient animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Rick mentioned, there is no support for gradient animation yet.

However, you can still apply a semitransparent gradient *on top* of the CSS transition and then just animate the background color (the effect will be very similar):

```
.outerBorder {
    display:inline-block;
    /*border: 3px solid #4d4d4d;*/  
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 1000ms ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 1000ms ease-in-out;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}

.outerBorder:hover {
    background-color: #b4d7dd; 
}

.innerBox {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    padding:15px;
    background-color:#fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.3)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255, 0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4d4d4d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
   background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NAVYX/

Answer (score 1):

There isn't support for gradient animations yet. As you are using jQuery you could write this functionality using [cssHooks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/), or simpler, have one gradient on top of the other, then animate the opacity to simulate the fade.